# function similar to dplyr::distinct with a cutoff

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe of points with x,y positions (in pixels) and would like to filter out all the points +/- 5 pixels. Is there a function similar to dplyr::distinct() but with a cutoff.

Example dataset:

X.1     X     Y 
     
     1   637   614
     2   559   503
     3   601   459
     4   601   459
     5   603   462
     6   604   460

I am expecting an output of :

X.1     X     Y 
     
     1   637   614
     2   559   503
     3   601   459  <- the first element is preserved.

Thanks

Comment: What do you expect as result?

Comment: I modified my original question to better explain the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to round your data to the nearest multiple of 5 and then use a regular distinct function:

```
X.1$x <- round(X.1$x/5)*5
X.1$y <- round(X.1$y/5)*5

distinct(X.1,.keep_all = TRUE)

#Output:
X.1  X  Y

1   635 615

2   560 505

3   600 560
```

Your problem may require a higher level of accuracy however.

Comment: I am validating the dataset with different pixel values and i find i get a degree of error by this method. Is there a way i can superimpose the indices which were not removed by the distinct onto the original dataframe ?

Comment: @Ret231 You could put a column that is the row number onto the X.1 dataset, then after the rounding, take just the row numbers of X.1 that are in the distinct dataset